# PHP - Ajax - Response is also class name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to get an success response from my ajax recall but it failed.
When I open the dev tool in chrome I can see the response and it is composed of my json response and also the class name which is triggered in my .php file. This throwns then an exception in my console.
This are the script how I made the call, triggering by a click of a button.

jquery.backend.js

```
$('#save-config-map').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax( {
    url: '../../ajax/ajax_config_map.php',
    success: function (response) {                  
      console.log(response.error);
    }
  });
});
```

ajax_config_map.php

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'loader.php');
use Db\DatabaseConfigMap;

$insertDataConfigMap = new DatabaseConfigMap();
$result = $insertDataConfigMap->insertConfigDataAllDB();

$results = array(
    'error' => $result
);

echo json_encode($results);
```

DatabaseConfigMap.php

```
namespace Db;
use \PDO;
use PDOException;

class DatabaseConfigMap extends DatabaseMain {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insertConfigDataAllDB()
        return 'Test';
    }
}
```

DatabaseMain.php

```
namespace Db;
use \PDO;
require_once(DATABASE_DIR);

class DatabaseMain
{
    protected string $servername;
    protected string $dbname;
    protected string $username;
    protected string $password;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s", DB_HOST, DB_DATABASE, DB_CHARSET);
        $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

loader.php <-- loading all my classes

```
$rootDir =CLASSES_DIR;
$autoload = function($className) use($rootDir){
    var_dump($className);
    $fileName = '';
    if($lastNameSpacePosition = strpos($className,'\\')){
        $namespace = substr($className, 0,$lastNameSpacePosition);
        $className = substr($className,$lastNameSpacePosition+1);
        $fileName = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$namespace).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    if(is_file($rootDir.$fileName.'.php')){
        require_once $rootDir.$fileName.'.php';
    }
};

spl_autoload_register($autoload);
```

I cut some code where I insert the data in my database. This code works very well but as I said, the response is:

```
string(20) "DB\DatabaseConfigMap"...{error: 'Test'}
error: "Test"
```

Thanks for all the help
Marcus

I used the dev tool from chrome to analyse the error and checked the board and google for solution.

Comment: That's coming from `var_dump($className);` in the `$autoload` function.

Comment: That's probably left over from debugging, you need to remove it.

Comment: @Barmar, holy sh**. Yes, you are right. I forgot to comment it out for further analyses.
Thank you very much for helping me very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in ajax that the response will be in json format

```
  $.ajax({
       url: 'example.com',
       data: {
            // key and values
        },
       dataType: 'json', // your case requires datatype json
})
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the response isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar right sir, but I was talking about dataType.
Might be possible I'm wrong

Comment: This is certainly necessary, but it won't fix the root problem.

Answer (score -1):

specify the  dataType: 'json' in

```
 $.post({
           url: ``,
           data: data_to_backend,
           dataType: 'json', // the return type format from backend
})
```

put this before your echo json_encode($x) for 200 response

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Comment: thank you. This is a standard config in another file which I include in all my ajax file. The answer for my fault is up from Barmar.

Comment: This doesn't help if the response isn't JSON.